Branch coverage issues for spdlog in gcov
We are using spdlog in our code and generating coverage reports for our .cpp files. It appears that gcov is reporting some lines as partially covered:
Line 1: SPDLOG_INFO( "{} Config {}", std::string(20, '='), std::string(20, '=') ); shows branchesToCover="8" coveredBranches="4"
Line 2: SPDLOG_INFO( "Username: {}", username ); shows branchesToCover="4" coveredBranches="2"
We want to address these branch coverage issues without making significant changes to the codebase by using gcov exclude flags. Is there a way to configure gcov settings within spdlog to avoid these branch coverage issues?

perhaps not what you are looking for, but lcov knows how to read gcov-generated data, and supports a bunch of options for liltering.
